# "It's easy to see that there exists an bijection"

Tags: general-topology

I'm working on a problem in Topology stated as follows

Pick $a\in \prod_{i\in I} X_i$. Let $F \subset I$ be a finite subset of $I$. Define 
$$
X_F := \{x_i : x_i \in X, x_i = a_i \text{ for } i \not \in F \} \subset \prod_{i \in I} X_i
$$
Show that $X_F$ is connected if all spaces $X_i$ are connected for all $i \in F$.

Now apperantly it's easy to see that there is an bijection $g:X_{f_1} \times X_{f_2} \times \dots \times X_{f_k} \to X_F$. Can someone help me see why there is such a bijection?

> If $X_F = \{ x : x_i \in X_i, x_i = a_i \text{ for } i \not \in F\}$ then I agree, but that is not what is said in the exercise.

Comment: What is $X$...?

Comment: I suppose that this (or $X_F=\{\,(x_i)_{i\in I}\in \prod_{i\in I}X_i: x_i=a_i \text{ for }i\notin F\,\}=\bigcap_{i\notin F}\pi_i^{-1}(a_i)$) is indeed meant

Comment: It's just a typo. "$x_i \in X_i$, and $x_i = a_i$ for $i \notin F$" was intended.

Comment: So are you agreeing with what I wrote in the yellow part? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I dont understand, that is exactly what is stated, without the $x_i :$ part? @DanielFischer

Comment: It's exactly what _you_ proposed (except for the "and" I added). In the first part, the subscript is missing, and $X$ is written instead of $X_i$. And I missed the part before the colon, that should be either $(x_i)$ to indicate the indexed family, or $x$ as the name of the map.